# Arraystretch in tabular environment produces misalignment

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

The following code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} r L{\textwidth * \real{0.8}}} 
\hline
Languages & Italian (native tongue), English (very fluent), German (beginner). \\
\hline
Chats & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  \\
\hline
Programming & C, Java, OCaml, Bash, Fortran. Currently learning Python and R. \\
\hline
\end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```

produces this:

[image]

If I add

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{4}
```

before the tabular code, the output is this:

[image]

If, additionally, I change the definition of `L` using the `p` column as follows

```
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
```

then I get this:

[image]

None of these is the output I want. I would like **every** cell to be **vertically centered**. Why does this happen? How can I fix it? I tried to use different solutions (such as `\setlength{\extrarowheight}{4pt}`), but all of them are affected by the same problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us (a) which document class you use and (b) how the `\real` macro is defined.

Comment: `m` column type loses all information about the internal baselines as it is `\vcenter` if you want text in a parbox to align with a `r` column use `p` (which is `vtop`)

Comment: `a4paper` is paper size, not a document class ... it seems, that you use `Awesome-CV`. Please, transform your code sniped to complete small document starting with `\documentclass[a4paper]{...}` end ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: First of all, I'm sorry if the question is not self-contained. I had already tried to do what @Zarko suggests, but it was too complex for me to extract the relevant code and make it compilable. I am not new to LaTeX, but as I said I'm using the Awesome-CV template, which uses several LaTeX functions that are beyond my knowledge. I hoped that the code I gave was sufficient, but if it's not I can try again to make it compilable.

Comment: your example doesn't need the cv class you could just use article and array package to make a single tabular

Comment: I've re-written the question from scratch. Let me know if it's clearer now. Thank you!

Comment: Why the complicated `\textwidth*\real{0.8}` instead of the much simpler `0.8\textwidth`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong tool:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}

\setlength{\heavyrulewidth}{\lightrulewidth}
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{12pt}% choose
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{12pt}% choose

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} r X @{}}
\toprule
Languages & Italian (native tongue), English (very fluent), German (beginner). \\
\midrule
Chats & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
        bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
        bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
        bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  \\
\midrule
Programming & C, Java, OCaml, Bash, Fortran. Currently learning Python and R. \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the label vertically centered with respect to the body (but I wouldn't do it), you can set the type of the `X` column to `m`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,array}

\setlength{\heavyrulewidth}{\lightrulewidth}
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{12pt}% choose
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{12pt}% choose
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} r X @{}}
\toprule
Languages & Italian (native tongue), English (very fluent), German (beginner). \\
\midrule
Chats & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
        bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
        bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
        bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  \\
\midrule
Programming & C, Java, OCaml, Bash, Fortran. Currently learning Python and R. \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I would like to have *every* cell vertically centered, but in your solution "Languages", "Chats" and "Programming" seem to be aligned to the first line of the cell on the right! Is there an easy fix?

Comment: @aerdna91 Yes, added.

Comment: Perfetct, thanks. Why do you say that "you wouldn't do it"? Also, can I ask you to suggest a good manual for tables?

Comment: @aerdna91 The manual of `booktabs` is very good for understanding how to build nice tables. I think that the picture explains by itself why I prefer the first way to the centering.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Issues with `m` column types is explained in David Carlisle answer. Unfortunately use of `\arraystreatch` and column type `p` doesn't gives equal vertical space between `hline`s and cells contents. Solution seems to be not use  `\arraystreatch` and desired vertical space obtain on different way, for example with rules provided by package `booktabs`:

Eddit:
For vertical centering of a text in the first column, you should add

```
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
```

with detewrminatin veritical space as used *egreg* in his answer the MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}X}
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{2ex}% choose
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{2ex}% choose

\usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2ex}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]% <-- added for preview
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{rX}
    \midrule
Languages & Italian (native tongue), English (very fluent), German (beginner). \\
    \midrule
Chats & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  \\
    \midrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

In above MWE instead `tabular` the `tabularx` environment is used. It gives equal column width as your (wrongly) used determination of the space between columns.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I would like to have *every* cell vertically centered, but in your solution "Languages" and "Chats" seem to be aligned to the first line of the cell on the right! Is there an easy fix?

Answer (score 0):

an `m` column type places the reference point in the vertical centre of its content without considering the internal baselines. so any alignment of text in an `m` column to text in surrounding columns is essentially accidental. (If you narrow the column slightly so that the text breaks over two lines, then it will re-align in this case)

`p` or `b` columns *do* set the reference point to an internal baseline (top or bottom line, respectively) and with `p` you get alignment again as shown below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\addtolength\textwidth{2cm}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{4}
\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{%
>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\centering
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} r L{0.8\textwidth}}
\hline
Languages & Italian (native tongue), English (very fluent), German (beginner). \\
\hline
Programming & C, Java, OCaml, Bash, Fortran. Currently learning Python and R. \\
\end{tabular*}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{%
>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\centering
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} r L{0.8\textwidth}}
\hline
Languages & Italian (native tongue), English (very fluent), German (beginner). \\
\hline
Programming & C, Java, OCaml, Bash, Fortran. Currently learning Python and R. \\
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've edited the question to make it clearer and self-contained, so your answer seems odd now. I'm sorry! Anyway, the solution you suggest still doesn't solve my problem (see the new question).